# How fisherface classifier works

Tags: opencv, classification, face-recognition

Can anybody explain me how OPENCV fisherfaceclassifier works? 
How it recognize the difference faces ?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that all OpenCV algorithms (usually) are based on a research papers or topics that can be researched and understood.

For FisherFace you can read about the background of it [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Fisherfaces) to understand exactly how it works, this article discussed the background and implementation.

As for implementation of the Fisherface *using*  (as your question is a little unclear) OpenCV provide a [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) on how to get up and running, they also explain some background and importantly **link out too all the underlying papers and research**

I didn't really think this question is appropriate for SO as you really could have just googled your question and come to the same answer. I just thought it might be useful to understand how OpenCV is built up.